# How do assert an empty interface back to a slice of my custom type?

Tags: go

I have 15 custom types in this application, and the processing I wish to do to them is actually very generic to them all.

In each case, I need to iterate over a slice of whatever type it is that I am working with.

an interface is what currently gets passed, but it certainly doesn't have to remain that way

I have the following code :

```
func ProcessSlice(in interface{}){
    switch reflect.TypeOf(p.in).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(p.in)

        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(p.in))
        }
    }
}
```

the fmt.Println is there for debugging, and I get the following sort of output :

```
[map[_Id:4K7qx_mUSbV-----------== name:<name ommited> _class:basic_organization] map[_Id:4K7qx_mUnvB-----------== name:<name omitted> _class:basic_organization]]
```

My real question here, is let's say I have the types :

```
MyCustomStructA,
MyCustomeStructB
```

and I bail into that function with a slice of either, how can I end up in that loop, working with actual struct items? Because at the minute, I wind up with a map, and that is not what I want here.

Comment: In your loop, you are doing `reflect.ValueOf(p.in)` again. Do you mean `s.Index(i)`?

Comment: that line is just for debugging - what I'd really like to do inside that loop is perform a switch or something and be able to create a new type that is the same as the ones in the slice passed in to this function.

Comment: `s.Index(i)` is going to get you the `Value` of the element at that index of the slice. From that, you should be able to get a new instance with something like `reflect.New(s.Index(i).Type())`.

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954646/iterating-over-an-array-of-interfaces .. ? i think its quite similar. .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making all of those custom types implement an interface which says that they're 'processable'. Then in `ProcessSlice()`, you can iterate over the slice elements and process those that implement the `Processable` interface. Something like this:

```
// Processable is a type that can be 'processed'
type Processable interface {
    Process()
}

// ProcessSlice processes a slice of types that can be processed
func ProcessSlice(in interface{}) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(in).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(in)

        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            v := s.Index(i).Interface()

            if p, ok := v.(Processable); ok {
                p.Process()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, all of the processing logic for a type can be attached to the type itself and you also wouldn't need to modify `ProcessSlice()` when adding new custom types.

Coming to the actual question, you can use a type switch on the slice value like this (though I prefer the interface way more)

```
// ProcessSliceConcreteTypes processes a slice of types based on the type of the slice
func ProcessSliceConcreteTypes(in interface{}) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(in).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(in)

        switch sv := s.Interface().(type) {
        case []S1:
            for _, s1 := range sv {
                s1.Process()
            }
        case []S2:
            for _, s2 := range sv {
                s2.Process()
            }
        default:
            // error here
        }
    }
}
```

(See it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FTlEA5tH3A7))

Comment: I like your interface idea best, too! But for some reason I am getting nil down inside the loop in the example code.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds where exactly do you get a `nil`? Can you make a playground link with some sample code?

Comment: Why even use the empty interface and reflection at this point? Your signature could be `func ProcessSliceConcreteTypes(in []Processable)` and then you just iterate over the slice calling `Process` on each element.

Comment: @Gavin that wouldn't work since a slice of struct types is not equivalent to a slice of interfaces so the code wouldn't compile. (OP says `I need to iterate over a slice of whatever type it is that I am working with.`)

Comment: I think there is still a simple way this can be accomplished while leveraging the compiler for type checking and avoiding reflection. Assuming each type has it's own logic for processing, why not make the slice of that type implement the `Processable` interface? At that point this function essentially becomes useless, and `slice.Process()` could be called from anywhere, where `slice` is a slice of 'whatever type it is that I am working with' and implements `Processable`.

Comment: @Gavin Yes, that'd work but that duplication of code is what OP wants to avoid in the first place I think. Defining a new slice type for each struct and then implementing a `slice.Process()` would mean almost duplicating ~10 lines of code (define type, implement the interface for the type, loop over elements; call Process() for each) for each such type.